# Select all records in MySQL unless record exist in another table

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have two MySQL tables. One is called `match_rail` and `match_complete`.

When a bill_number from match_rail is actioned, the record moves to the `match_complete` table and should no longer be displayed in the `match_rail` table.

The `match_rail` table is refreshed hourly. Therefore I need to make sure not to display the same `bill_number` if it already exists in the `match_complete` table.

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT
   mr.RAMP
   mr.ETA
   mr.BILL_NUMBER
   // few more columns
 FROM
   matchback_rail mr
 JOIN
   matchback_complete mc ON mr.BILL_NUMBER = mc.BILL_NUMBER
```

The above query gives me 0 records.  It should give me all records except the ones that exist in both tables.

Not sure if I should be using a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
     mr.RAMP
     mr.ETA
     mr.BILL_NUMBER
     // few more columns
FROM
     matchback_rail mr
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM matchback_complete
                 WHERE BILL_NUMBER = mr.BILL_NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a `LEFT JOIN`, this gives all records in `mr`, even if there is nothing joined. Then use `WHERE` to filter out the ones you don't want.

```
SELECT
   mr.RAMP
   mr.ETA
   mr.BILL_NUMBER
   // few more columns
 FROM
   matchback_rail mr
 LEFT JOIN
   matchback_complete mc ON mr.BILL_NUMBER = mc.BILL_NUMBER
 WHERE mc.BILL_NUMBER IS NULL
```